# Add 1000 Constraints in linear programing using R lpSolve

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a big linear model, but I'm  having a problem
to add more variables/constraints. For example, I want to add constraints without adding 
the others zeros (0) in the matrix (f.con) like in the example:

```
library(linprog)
f.obj <- c(3,24,79,140,230,306,338,
           26,78,145,226,309,336,354,
           146,250,312,364,417,496,508,
           314,382,424,472,503,525,548)
f.con <- matrix (c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1)             
                 ,nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)
f.rhs <- c(10,22,8,30)
f.dir <- c("<=", "<=","<=","<=")
lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)

n<-lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$solution
n
```

Thank you!

Comment: The string "i" is not a word in the English language.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're after something like this:

```
makef.con <- function(f.obj,f.dir){
  k      <- length(f.dir)
  Nconst <- length(f.obj) / k
  Diag   <- diag(k)
  c(matrix(rep(Diag, each = Nconst), nrow = k, byrow = TRUE))
}
all(makef.con(f.obj,f.dir) == f.con)
[1] TRUE
```

though to be honest, I'm not familiar with what you're doing, so you may need to play with this so that it generalizes to your needs