# Create a matrix with loop in R

Tags: r, matrix

I trying to create a loop in R, that replace im my matrix the 0 by 1 on in each 2 rows, 
but I just can create one matrix with number 1. I don´t know how to implement it fast and right!

R code

```
i<-1
r<-1
l<-1
repeat{
    while(i<3){
        if(l<7) {
            r<-rbind(r,1) 
            l<-l+1
        }else{
            r<-cbind(r,1)
            i<-i+1
            l<-1
        }
    }
}
```

start example matrix

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

final matrix:

```
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
0   0   1
```

Comment: Are you just trying to create the final matrix? Because there are much simpler and efficient ways of creating the final matrix.

Comment: it looks like this is you are rephrasing this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494201/add-1000-constraints-in-linear-programing-using-r-lpsolve

Answer (score 11):

Is it a requirement to use a `for` loop? R works best using vectorized statements, e.g.:

```
diag(3)[rep(1:3, each = 2), ]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    1    0
# [5,]    0    0    1
# [6,]    0    0    1
```